# Cocos2d-js: effect on cocos2d-js application running on browser while a move from one application to another application

Tags: cocos2d-x, collision-detection, game-physics, cocos2d-js

i was running parkour game given on cocos2d website on my browser. everything was working fine, but when i move from my browser to sublime text and returned to my browser, the running player start to show some unexpected behaviour, the player disappeared from its position and and after few second it fall on the ground and then start running again .whenever i move from one application to another it happens.

i don't why its happening. could some one tell me  how to prevent this from happen?

here is the code for animation layer:-

```
       var AnimationLayer = cc.Layer.extend({
spriteSheet: null,
runningAction: null,
sprite: null,
space:null,
body:null,
shape:null,

ctor:function (space) {
    this._super();
    this.space = space;
    this.init();

    this._debugNode = cc.PhysicsDebugNode.create(this.space);
    this._debugNode.setVisible(false);
    // Parallax ratio and offset
    this.addChild(this._debugNode, 10);
},
init:function () {
    this._super();

    // create sprite sheet
    cc.spriteFrameCache.addSpriteFrames(res.runner_plist);
    this.spriteSheet = cc.SpriteBatchNode.create(res.runner_png);
    this.addChild(this.spriteSheet);


    // init runningAction
    var animFrames = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        var str = "runner" + i + ".png";
        var frame = cc.spriteFrameCache.getSpriteFrame(str);
        animFrames.push(frame);
    }

    var animation = cc.Animation.create(animFrames, 0.1);
    this.runningAction = cc.RepeatForever.create(cc.Animate.create(animation));


    //create runner through physic engine
    this.sprite = cc.PhysicsSprite.create("#runner0.png");
    var contentSize = this.sprite.getContentSize();
    // init body
    this.body = new cp.Body(1, cp.momentForBox(1, contentSize.width, contentSize.height));
    this.body.p = cc.p(g_runnerStartX, g_groundHight + contentSize.height / 2);
    this.body.applyImpulse(cp.v(150, 0), cp.v(0, 0));//run speed
    this.space.addBody(this.body);
    //init shape
    this.shape = new cp.BoxShape(this.body, contentSize.width - 14, contentSize.height);
    this.space.addShape(this.shape);

    this.sprite.setBody(this.body);
    this.sprite.runAction(this.runningAction);

    this.spriteSheet.addChild(this.sprite);

    this.scheduleUpdate();
},

getEyeX:function () {
    return this.sprite.getPositionX() - g_runnerStartX;
}});
```

and this is the code for playScene.js:-

```
    var PlayScene = cc.Scene.extend({
space:null,
gameLayer:null,
// init space of chipmunk
initPhysics:function() {
    this.space = new cp.Space();
    // Gravity
    this.space.gravity = cp.v(0, -350);
    // set up Walls
    var wallBottom = new cp.SegmentShape(this.space.staticBody,
        cp.v(0, g_groundHight),// start point
        cp.v(4294967295, g_groundHight),// MAX INT:4294967295
        0);// thickness of wall
    this.space.addStaticShape(wallBottom);
},
onEnter:function () {
    this._super();
    this.initPhysics();



    this.gameLayer = cc.Layer.create();

    //add three layer in the right order
    this.gameLayer.addChild(new BackgroundLayer(), 0, TagOfLayer.background);
    this.gameLayer.addChild(new AnimationLayer(this.space), 0, TagOfLayer.Animation);
    this.addChild(this.gameLayer);
    this.addChild(new StatusLayer(), 0, TagOfLayer.Status);

    this.scheduleUpdate();

},
update:function (dt) {
    // chipmunk step
    this.space.step(dt);
    var animationLayer = this.gameLayer.getChildByTag(TagOfLayer.Animation);
    var eyeX = animationLayer.getEyeX();

    this.gameLayer.setPosition(cc.p(-eyeX,0));
}
```

});

Comment: post relevant sections of the code, ie movement, collision detection

Comment: When you say "but when i move from my browser to sublime text and returned to my browser,", do you mean you just minimize the browser and then maximize that window again?

The safest bet would be to ensure that the game is pausing when the browser's tab it's in loses focus (althought this should be happening by default..)

Comment: yes @SebastiánVansteenkiste, but why this is happening ?

Comment: My best guess is that the physics engine is still running althought the game get's paused. This is most likely because, for performance reasons, the physics engine works on it's own thread (or rather, web worker). You need to find a way to manually pause it, but I haven't dealt with it so I can't say.
The quickest route will probably be searching/asking in the cocos2d-x forums.
Good luck!

Comment: thnks @SebastiánVansteenkiste

Comment: No prob. Although, I've been reading a bit into it, and that `update` method seems to be responsible to update the world state, so I think my previous guess was wrong? Just for testing, you could add a `this.i=0;` in your `initPhysics`, and a `console.log(i++);` in that `update` function, then run the game, look at the console and watch if the numbers keep on changing when the window loses focus!

Comment: Oh! I just discovered something you are going to like (I'm starting to think the problem might be in how the shapes are setted up), right after you define `this.space = new cp.Space();`, add these lines of code: `this._debugNode = new cc.PhysicsDebugNode(this.space);
    this._debugNode.visible = true ;
    this.addChild( this._debugNode );` this will enable the showing of debug physics shapes and showl help you understand how the physics engine behaves :D

Comment: @SebastiánVansteenkiste i appreciate your effort, but they didn't solve my problem, i did both the things as you said, although i have learned new things from it but still my problem is unsolved. thanks for your effort

Comment: Yep, that's why I'm just commening and not posting as an answer ;) Anyway, I've taken this as an opportunity to try and learn how Chipmunk goes together with PhysicsSprite in Cocos2D-JS, and I've managed to replicate this same issue. I think I've found a few leads, I'll post an answer if I find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this may or may not solve the issue some scenarios, but after looking at it profoundly, the biggest suspect seems to be a lack of steps in the calculations of Chipmunk when the framerate drops (which appears to happen when you resize or minimize/maximize the screen).

The closest thing to a fix that I've found comes from a lead in [this post in the forums](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/collision-detection-only-performance/15485), and which I've adapted it like this: where you have `this.space.step(dt);` in your update function, change it for the following:

```
var timeWindow = 1/60; //replace by your configured FPS rate if it's not 60
var steps = Math.ceil(dt / timeWindow);
var i = 0;
for (; i < steps; i++) {
  this.space.step(timeWindow);
}
```

This should ensure that even if your application drops below 60fps the physics simulation will be updated properly, and this problem should not happen anymore.

Comment: you solved my problem but the player seems blur, while before that i could see him clearly

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. Did you change anything else? Was the framerate different before and after you changing the function?