# physics body moves in browser but not on mac or ios

Tags: cocos2d-x, chipmunk, cocos2d-js

i was trying to move the physics body by changing its coordinate in scheduler and i used this code. if i run this code in browser it will work but after js binding it doesn't work on mac or ios. Physics body doesn't move at all on these devices

```
init: function{
 var mass = 1;    
var width = 1, height = 1;
this.playerBody = new cp.Body(mass , cp.momentForBox(mass, width, height));
this.space.addBody(this.playerBody);

this.schedule(this.move);
},
move: function(dt){
this.space.step(dt);
this.playerBody.getPos().x += 2 * dt;
this.playerBody.getPos().y += 2 * dt;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after adding few lines my player started to move in mac

```
init: function{
var mass = 1;    
var width = 1, height = 1;
this.playerBody = new cp.Body(mass , cp.momentForBox(mass, width, height));
this.space.addBody(this.playerBody);

this.schedule(this.move);
},
move: function(dt){
this.space.step(dt);
var a = this.playerBody.local2World(this.playerBody.p);
a.y += 2 * dt;
a.x += 2 * dt ;
a = this.playerBody.world2Local(a);
this.playerBody.p = a;
}
```

but i don't have explanation of this code

Comment: OK.. This is definately strange. It could be because of some sort of access protection issue.. Could you please file a bug report over at the official site's issue tracker describing this whole proccess?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing that `getPos()` from those lines, leave them at: `this.playerBody.p.x += 2 * dt;`. I think that's most likely the cause of your problem.

---

Additionally, avoid manipulating the coordinates yourself and let the physics engine handle everything.

For example, you could assign the velocity by hand like this:

```
init: function{
  var mass = 1;    
  var width = 1, height = 1;
  var vx = 1, vy = 1;
  this.playerBody = new cp.Body(mass , cp.momentForBox(mass, width, height));
  this.space.addBody(this.playerBody);
  this.playerBody.vx = vx;
  this.playerBody.vy = vy;

  this.schedule(this.move);
},

move: function(dt){
  this.space.step(dt);
}
```

Or, if you want to give a "bump" to the object in a certain direction, you could use `applyImpulse` like this:

```
init: function{
  var mass = 1;    
  var width = 1, height = 1;
  var fx = 1, fy = 1;
  this.playerBody = new cp.Body(mass , cp.momentForBox(mass, width, height));
  this.space.addBody(this.playerBody);
  this.playerBody.applyImpuse(cp.v(fx, fy), cp.v(0,0));

  this.schedule(this.move);
},

move: function(dt){
  this.space.step(dt);
}
```

Or, if you want to apply a constant force to the object, change `applyImpulse` to `applyForce` in that last example.

Note: the `cp.v(0,0)` parameter is telling the engine to apply the force to the center of the object, so it should not rotate.

PS: if (and only if) you happen to see some strange behaviour with the physics simulation, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25637471/cocos2d-js-effect-on-cocos2d-js-application-running-on-browser-while-a-move-fro/25955291#25955291).

Comment: first, i have tried "this.playerBody.x" but it is not working because there is no such property in Body class. Moreover, i know all these things you said, i just want to know why i am not able to change the coordinate of physics body in mac however i can change them in browser without any trouble

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo. It's `this.playerBody.p.x`.

Comment: 'this.playerBody.getPos().x' and 'this.playerBody.p.x' both statement are same because ** getPos()** returns object p, so you get it by function or access it directly both the process will access p object